# Remove non-words from a string using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

How can I write a regular expression that will match words that are not purely letters

and then remove them

> Jobs CAR0 PAPER J! #$4A

and the results should be

> Jobs PAPER

I tried this and it seemed to match the words I want to keep. How can I write the opposite of this?

> \b[a-zA-Z]+\b

UPDATE:

A single letter by itself is fine just not mixed with non-letters

Comment: `/\b[^A-Z]\b/i`

Comment: "/[^A-Za-z ]/" this is the regex

Comment: The `\b[a-zA-Z]+\b`  also keeps `J`. Marc's suggestion results in `JobsCAR0PAPERJ! #$4A`

Comment: I really do not want to post [`\s*(?!\p{L}+(?!\S))\S+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs*%28%3f!%5cp%7bL%7d%2b%28%3f!%5cS%29%29%5cS%2b&i=Jobs+CAR0+PAPER+J!+%23%244A&r=&o=s). The LINQ related answer is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with linq !

```
string words = "Jobs CAR0 PAPER J! #$4A";


var result = words.Split(' ').Where(x => x.All(char.IsLetter));
var stringResult = String.Join(" ", result);
```

Comment: which method is more efficient?

Comment: @Jasmine I will choose linq, because it is easy to understand and to read. At the end is personal preference. For current case you should not bother about efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

`\b[a-zA-Z]{2,}\b` would produce the desired result, although more use-cases would produce a more robust expression.

https://regex101.com/r/o1ZY45/1